# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client,After converting 3.5 to 4.0 ver

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have converted my web application from 3.4 to 4.0, Its converted and working, But in text box when i am giving some space and trying to save the data it is showing the error. A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (PageContent$DisplayTextMode$txbText="as b g
").

in web.cofig, I already added

```
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
   <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
   <pages validateRequest="false" maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" enableEventValidation="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
```

in previous version(3.5) every thing was working fine, I was not getting any error.

how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed the web.config and added new and in that i added

```
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="250000" maxRequestLength="2097151"  requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
```

Now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  `ValidateRequest="false"`  to the `<%@ Page .. %>`

Answer (score 0):

please make sure your application is targeting the .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: Can you please make sure  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
   <pages validateRequest="false"/> correctly set in web.config and please restart the IIS after that and try again. It should work out.

Comment: yes its properly set and again i restart my IIS but its not working i am getting the same problem